# How can I convert a node property into a virtual node and generate a [virtual] relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently learning cypher but trying to figure out how to accomplish the following.

### My data

I have a set of nodes in Neo4j that have properties. These properties are seldom used and so having actual nodes does not make much sense. My example below is a list of country nodes with a property of name and continent. We don't often use continent, but it's still there for informational purposes.

```
[
    {
        name: "Australia",
        continent: "Oceania"
    },
    {
        name: "Canada",
        continent: "North America"
    },
    {
        name: "New Zealand",
        continent: "Oceania"
    },
    {
        name: "United States",
        continent: "North America"
    }
]
```

### What I want

What we're looking to generate is a virtual node + relationship for each continent so we can see which countries belong to which continents. So, one node per continent and one node per country with multiple relationships from a single continent to the countries within.

[image: image of node/relationships I want]

### What I have

What I have so far is below - but it's just gives me disconnected continent nodes for each of the continent values it finds without grouping them.

```
Match (c:Country)
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Continent'],{name:c.continent}) yield node as s
Return c, apoc.create.vRelationship(s,'HAS_COUNTRY',{},c), s
```

How can I query with cypher to generate virtual nodes and relationships and group on a specific node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your query, you generate one continent per row and thus 4 of them, that's why you see disconnected continents.

You need to group countries of the same continent together and create on continent only for them

```
MATCH (c:Country)
WITH c.continent AS continent, collect(c) AS countries
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Continent'],{name: continent}) yield node AS s
UNWIND countries AS c
RETURN c, s, apoc.create.vRelationship(s,'HAS_COUNTRY',{},c)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If I understand this correctly then, you're collecting/grouping countries by continent, then creating the continent, then unwinding them (like exploding a list) and generating the relationships. Whereas I was simply creating a node per country continent property and then generating a relationship resulting in 1:1 relationships.

Comment: Correct, I group before so I make sure to generate the continent only once